# Is logistic regression actually a regression algorithm?

Tags: algorithms, logistic-regression

The usual definition of regression (as far as I am aware) is *predicting a continuous output variable from a given set of input variables*.

Logistic regression is a binary classification algorithm, so it produces a categorical output.

Is it really a regression algorithm? If so, why?

Answer (score 36, accepted):

Logistic regression is regression, first and foremost. It becomes a classifier by adding a decision rule. I will give an example that goes backwards. That is, instead of taking data and fitting a model, I'm going to start with the model in order to show how this is truly a regression problem.

In logistic regression, we are modeling the log odds, or logit, that an event occurs, which is a continuous quantity. If the probability that event $A$ occurs is $P(A)$, the odds are:

$$\frac{P(A)}{1 - P(A)}$$

The log odds, then, are:

$$\log \left( \frac{P(A)}{1 - P(A)}\right)$$

As in linear regression, we model this with a linear combination of coefficients and predictors:

$$\operatorname{logit} = b_0 + b_1x_1 + b_2x_2 + \cdots$$

Imagine we are given a model of whether a person has gray hair. Our model uses age as the only predictor. Here, our event A = a person has gray hair:

log odds of gray hair = -10 + 0.25 * age

...Regression! Here is some Python code and a plot:

```
%matplotlib inline
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import seaborn as sns

x = np.linspace(0, 100, 100)

def log_odds(x):
    return -10 + .25 * x

plt.plot(x, log_odds(x))
plt.xlabel("age")
plt.ylabel("log odds of gray hair")
```

[image: plot of the log odds for our toy example]

Now, let's make it a classifier. First, we need to transform the log odds to get out our probability $P(A)$. We can use the sigmoid function:

$$P(A) = \frac1{1 + \exp(-\text{log odds}))}$$

Here's the code:

```
plt.plot(x, 1 / (1 + np.exp(-log_odds(x))))
plt.xlabel("age")
plt.ylabel("probability of gray hair")
```

[image: plot of the probability of gray hair for our toy example]

The last thing we need to make this a classifier is to add a decision rule. One very common rule is to classify a success whenever $P(A) > 0.5$. We will adopt that rule, which implies that our classifier will predict gray hair whenever a person is older than 40 and will predict non-gray hair whenever a person is under 40.

Logistic regression works great as a classifier in more realistic examples too, but before it can be a classifier, it must be a regression technique!

Comment: Though in practice people use logistic regression as synonym of logistic regression+binary classifier.

Answer (score 11):

**Short Answer**

Yes, logistic regression is a regression algorithm and it does predict a continuous outcome: the probability of an event.  That we use it as a binary classifier is due to the interpretation of the outcome.

**Detail**

Logistic regression is a type of generalize linear regression model.

In an ordinary linear regression model, a continuous outcome, `y`, is modeled as the sum of the product of predictors and their effect:

```
y = b_0 + b_1 * x_1 + b_2 * x_2 + ... b_n * x_n + e
```

where `e` is the error.

Generalized linear models do not model `y` directly.  Instead, they use transformations to expand the domain of `y` to all real numbers.  This transformation is called the link function.  For logistic regression the link function is the logit function (usually, see note below).

The logit function is defined as

```
ln(y/(1 + y))
```

Thus the form of logistic regression is:

```
ln(y/(1 + y)) = b_0 + b_1 * x_1 + b_2 * x_2 + ... b_n * x_n + e
```

where `y` is the probability of an event.

The fact that we use it as a binary classifier is due to the interpretation of the outcome.

Note: probit is another link function used for logistic regression but logit is the most widely used.

Answer (score 0):

As you discuss, the definition of regression is predicting a continuous variable. [Logistic regression](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logistic_regression) is a binary classifier.  Logistic regression is the application of a logit function on the output of a usual regression approach. Logit function turns $(-\infty, +\infty)$ to $[0,1]$. I think it is just for historical reasons that it keeps that name.

Saying something like "I did some regression to classify images. In particular I used logistic regression." is wrong.

Comment: Logistic regression can be used as a binary classifier, but it isn't inherently one.  You could be using it to estimate odds or determine the relationship of a predictor variable to the outcome.

Answer (score 0):

To put it simply any hypothetical function $f$ makes for regression algorithm if $f:X\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$. Thus logistic function which is $P(Y=1|\lambda, x)=\dfrac{1}{1+e^{-\lambda^Tx}} \in [0,1]$ makes for a regression algorithm. Here $\lambda$ is coefficient or hyperplane found from trained datasets & $x$ is a data point. Here, $sign(P(Y=1|\lambda, x))$ is taken as class.